# Email Footer - creating HTML footer but when added to outlook white space appears between the slices

Tags: html, html-table, outlook

I've created an email footer by creating an image in photoshop and then slicing the image, which generates a base code. However, when it is added to Outlook, white space appears in the table and can't remove. I've tried various styles but it still has space.

[Please see image where the 2 gaps are, there would be more gaps but because of the white background they don't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ0j8.png)

The code is below, any advice would be much appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style meadia="screen" type="text/css">
        td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0cm; }
        img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
    </style> 
    </head>
    

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Website Style</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (Website Style.pdf) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="601" height="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_01.png" width="600" height="47" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="47" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="3">
                <a href="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_02.png" width="292" height="118" alt=""></a></td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_03.png" width="308" height="82" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="82" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_04.png" width="308" height="27" alt=""></a></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="27" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <a href="tel:0123456789"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_05.png" width="308" height="24" alt=""></a></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="9" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_06.png" width="292" height="15" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="15" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_07.png" width="22" height="120" alt=""></td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FBPAGE/"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_08.png" width="80" height="87" alt=""></a></td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/TWITTERPAGE"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_09.png" width="78" height="87" alt=""></a></td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/LINKEDINPAGE"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_10.png" width="81" height="87" alt=""></a></td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_11.png" width="31" height="87" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_12.png" width="308" height="31" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="31" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/"><img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_13.png" width="308" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="35" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_14.png" width="308" height="54" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="21" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <img src="https://www.WEBSITE.co.uk//uploads/Website-Style_15.png" width="270" height="33" alt=""></td>
            <td>
                <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="33" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of the way Outlook renders HTML using Microsoft Word, automatically adding whitespace around certain elements.

I always include these lines of CSS to prevent the styling that is applied automatically by email clients.

```css
       table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        img, a img {
            border: 0;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
        table, td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0;
            mso-table-rspace: 0;
        }

        /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }
```

Maybe try adding these and see if it helps?

Comment: Hiya, thanks for that - it's still showing the gaps in the doc. Is there an alternative way to create a footer on Photoshop/illustrator?